# Linear algebra: Find || || u || v ||

Tags: linear-algebra

Let u = (2, 4, 1) and v = (-3, 5, -1).

The question asks me to find `|| ||u||v||` but I don't know exactly what that means as I've never seen something written like this (other than guessing that it's a question about parallels). I've searched everywhere for a question similar to this but I couldn't find anything. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Probably $\lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert$ signifies the (Euclidean) norm of the vector $\mathbf{x}$, so
$\lVert (x_1,x_2,x_3) \rVert = \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}$.

You probably have a typo and mean $\lVert \mathbf{u}\rVert \lVert \mathbf{v}\rVert$, the product of $\lVert \mathbf{u}\rVert$ and $\lVert \mathbf{v}\rVert$.

Or, possibly you mean $\Big\lVert \underbrace{\lVert \mathbf{u}\rVert \mathbf{v}}_\textrm{scalar times vector} \Big\rVert$ (as @Chessanator suggests)? Your notation is difficult to understand without using MathJax.

Answer (score 1):

The notation of those double-bars refers to the norm on the vector space (usually the euclidean norm $||x||=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}$). Knowing this, we can see how the expression in your question was constructed:

- Start with the vector $u$ and take its norm $||u||$.
- $||u||$ is a real number - a scalar - so we can take any other vector $v$ and multiply it by that scalar to get $||u||v$.
- $||u||v$ is a vector. Therefore, we can take its norm $||(||u||v)||$.

This is subtly different to the expression $||u||.||v||$ mentioned by Jagol95 in the comment. However, knowing the properties of norms it turns out that the two expressions are actually equal. I wouldn't be surprised if your teacher follows up by getting you to confirm this for the specific example (You should probably attempt this even if they don't).